# How to check if a form has no input fields and if so set the focus to an anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to check if a specific form has any input fields in it? Or if it has no input fields?

**Update:**

Also how do I return the focus to a button on page load if the condition is met?
The below doesn't seem to work

```
var numInputs = $("#forgotPassword").find("input:visible").length;
if(numInputs == 0){
$('.button-class > a').focus(); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just select all the inputs inside the form and check to see how many come back

```
var numInputs = $("#formId input").length;

if (numInputs === 0)
   console.log("no inputs");
```

And of course if you'd like to include textareas and selects

```
var numInputs = $("#formId input, #formId textarea, #formId select").length;
```

or more simply:

```
var numInputs = $("#formId").find("input, textarea, select").length;
```

---

**EDIT**

To exclude hidden inputs, you can use the `:visible` pseudoselector

```
var numInputs = $("#formId input:visible").length;
```

Comment: how do I exclude hidden inputs?

Comment: Thank you Adam, it works. Can you please check the updated question?

Comment: It works when I access it this way $('#formId > columns > .button-class > a').focus();

Comment: @Altair - I'm guessing the other way, from your comment above, works since it's more specific.  I'm guessing $(".buttn-class > a") is picking up multiple items in its result set and winding up focusing the last one

Comment: It works with 
var x=document.getElementById("forgotPassword").getElementsByTagName("a");
x[0].focus();

Comment: @Altair - if that works then you should be able to also do:  `$("#forgotPassword a:first").focus();`

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the selector result contains any elements (here I assume that by input field you mean text input fields):

```
$('#myform').find('input[type="text"]').length
```